# variable declared outside jQuery.each becomes undefined within jQuery.each body

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I was facing some iisue with jQuery.each. I have declared a varible outside jquery.each satement. After first time of initialization of variable from jquery.each body the variable is not available for the next iteration. It says undefined.

Here is the sample code

```
var cname= '';

jQuery.each(candidate_arr['data'], function(index, data){
    if(index == 0){
        jQuery('.list').append('<li class="cname">'+ data['cname'] +'</li>');
        cname= data['cname'];
    }

    if(cname != data['cname']){ 
        // cname is undefined for index = 1, 2, 3....
        jQuery('.list').append('<li class="cname">'+ data['cname'] +'</li>');
        var cname = data['cname'];
    }


    jQuery('.list').append('<li>'+ data['candidate_name'] +'</li>');
})
```

Comment: Can you show what `candidate_arr` looks like? And try by removing `var` from `var cname = data['cname'];` as this creates a local `cname` variable.

Comment: have you checked to ensure that the assignment is happening? debug?

Comment: Yes. I see it by creating breakpoints and seen the intermediate values.

Comment: @WaleedIqbal Yes variables are look alike. Actually it comes from db from same table.

Comment: the scope within the callback function is different. you can just use normal js looping over the object

Comment: @CME64 Yes. Actually I am working on its alternative. But I want to know why this happening and what could be done in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope in the call back function is different so the variable will not be accessible

try a normal js loop

```
var cname= '';
var candidate_arr = {
  data: [{cname:"123"},{cname:"1234"},{cname:"1235"}]

};

for(var index=0; index< candidate_arr['data'].length;index++){
  var data = candidate_arr['data'][index];
  console.log(data);
  console.log(cname);
    if(index == 0){
        jQuery('.list').append('<li class="cname">'+ data['cname'] +'</li>');
        cname= data['cname'];
    }

    if(cname != data['cname']){ 
        // cname is undefined for index = 1, 2, 3....
        jQuery('.list').append('<li class="cname">'+ data['cname'] +'</li>');
        var cname = data['cname'];
    }


    jQuery('.list').append('<li>'+ data['candidate_name'] +'</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set inside the each block `var cname` is it tell to the JavaScript engine to create a new variable `cname` in each iteration. It to not use the global variable instance of the variable outside of the block.

You should learn about variables scopes in JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var